# Why is my express-session cookie being sent by API but not picked up in browser?

Tags: express, redis, express-session

Cookie in express session is being sent by API but not picked up in browser. As a result a new session is being generated per API call

I am using express-session with Express backend and Vue frontend.

I have added an abbreviated version of the relevant code below:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const session = require("express-session");
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const redis = require("ioredis");
const RedisStore = require("connect-redis").default;

//Configure redis client
const redisClient = redis.createClient({
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  port: 3002,
});

redisClient.on("error", function (err) {
  console.log("Could not establish a connection with redis. " + err);
});
redisClient.on("connect", function (err) {
  console.log("Connected to redis successfully");
});

app.use(
  session({
    secret: "megaultrasupersecret",
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient }),
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
      sameSite: "none",
      secure: false,
      httpOnly: false,
    },
  })
);
app.use(cookieParser("megaultrasupersecret"));

app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: ["http://localhost:5173"],
  })
);
```

I've researched various solutions such as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58356055/why-are-my-express-sessions-not-persisting-and-why-am-i-getting-a-new-session-o). Many call for 'secure' to be set to false, which I already have.

I set debug mode of express-session when running my server and can see the cookie getting set initially -

express-session saving 3k7qKWwHSuWcz3eE--vQu-EENIvQ0WIk +1ms
express-session set-cookie connect.sid=s%3A3k7qKWwHSuWcz3eE--vQu-EENIvQ0WIk.1i%2Fsaux3bkiyYiKzBVxaMJzqD%2FWbuaACkPwbW4Ql2aA; Path=/; SameSite=None +1ms

But then the next time my backend is called the logs read

express-session no SID sent, generating session +13ms

I also tried using mongo-store as well as Redis as the store.

Various solutions also call for 'saveUninitialized' to be false. I've tried it with both values with the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I could see Set-Cookie being returned in the response header, and ended up changing a whole lot of settings while troubleshooting. Below are the settings that finally worked for me. I think the pivotal change was using fetch on the FE instead of Axios, and taking 'samesite': 'None' out of the options for creating the cookie on the BE. If anybody has any additional feedback on this curious to know - not sure why this didn't work with Axios.
https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2020/01/get-ready-for-new-samesitenone-secure
BE portion:

```
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "megaultrasupersecret",
    saveUninitialized: true,
    name: "appName",
    store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient }),
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 1800 * 24,
      secure: false,
      httpOnly: false,
      domain: "localhost",
      path: "/",
    },
  })
);
app.use(cookieParser("megaultrasupersecret"));

app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: ["http://localhost:5173"],
    exposedHeaders: ["set-cookie", "ajax_redirect"],
    preflightContinue: true,
    methods: ["GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS"],
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
  })
);
```

FE portion (example of updated API call to BE):

```
getRecentlyCreatedForums() {
      const recentlyCreatedForums = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/forum', {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'cors',
        credentials: 'include'
      }).then((data) => data.json().then((data) => data))
```